# Split text columns into two columns in Pandas DataFrame, for different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have six different dataframes, some of this dataframes have 'NaN' values. I tried it without the if statements and it only worked on the dataframe that doesn't have 'NaN' values (I get this error: "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key" when I try it on the other dfs). What I'm trying to do is to create a function to split the df columns into two (air quality values and the unit).

```
def formatting(df):
    """ split text columns into two columns and changes data type"""

    # setting all floats to 2 digits in general
    pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2f}".format

    # NO2
    if 'NO2' != 'NaN':
        df[['NO2', 'NO2_UNIT']] = df.NO2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(' ')))
        if 'NO2' != 'NaN':
            df['NO2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['NO2'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # SO2
    if 'SO2' != 'NaN':
        df[['SO2', 'SO2_UNIT']] = df.SO2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(' ')))
        if 'SO2' != 'NaN':
            df['SO2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['SO2'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # 03
    if 'O3' != 'NaN':
        df[['O3', 'O3_UNIT']] = df.O3.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(' ')))
        if 'O3' != 'NaN':
            df['O3'] = pd.to_numeric(df['O3'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # PM10
    if 'PM10' != 'NaN':
        df[['PM10', 'PM10_UNIT']] = df.PM10.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(' ')))
        if 'PM10' != 'NaN':
            df['PM10'] = pd.to_numeric(df['PM10'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # PM2.5
    if 'PM2.5' != 'NaN':
        df.rename(columns={'PM2.5': 'PM25'}, inplace = True)
        df[['PM25', 'PM25_UNIT']] = df.PM25.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'PM2.5' != 'NaN':
            df['PM25'] = pd.to_numeric(df['PM25'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # CO
    if 'CO' != 'NaN':
        df[['CO', 'CO_UNIT']] = df.CO.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'CO' != 'NaN':
            df['CO'] = pd.to_numeric(df['CO'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # TEMP
    if 'TEMP' != 'NaN':
        df[['TEMP', 'TEMP_UNIT']] = df.TEMP.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'TEMP' != 'NaN':
            df['TEMP'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TEMP'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # HUM
    if 'HUM' != 'NaN':
        df[['HUM', 'HUM_UNIT']] = df.HUM.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'HUM' != 'NaN':
            df['HUM'] = pd.to_numeric(df['HUM'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # AIRPRES
    if 'AIRPRES' != 'NaN':
        df[['AIRPRES', 'AIRPRES_UNIT']] = df.AIRPRES.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'AIRPRES' != 'NaN':
            df['AIRPRES'] = df['AIRPRES'].replace(',', '', regex=True)
            df['AIRPRES'] = pd.to_numeric(df['AIRPRES'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # WS
    if 'WS' != 'NaN':
        df[['WS', 'WS_UNIT']] = df.WS.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'WS' != 'NaN':
            df['WS'] = pd.to_numeric(df['WS'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # WD
    if 'WD' != 'NaN':
        df[['WD', 'WD_UNIT']] = df.WD.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'WD' != 'NaN':
            df['WD'] = pd.to_numeric(df['WD'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # NO
    if 'NO' != 'NaN':
        df[['NO', 'NO_UNIT']] = df.NO.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'NO' != 'NaN':
            df['NO'] = pd.to_numeric(df['NO'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # BENZENE
    if 'BENZENE' != 'NaN':
        df[['BENZENE', 'BENZENE_UNIT']] = df.BENZENE.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(" ")))
        if 'BENZENE' != 'NaN':
            df['BENZENE'] = pd.to_numeric(df['BENZENE'], downcast="float")
    else:
        pass

    # order columns
    df = df[['TIMESTAMP', 'NO2', 'NO2_UNIT', 'SO2', 'SO2_UNIT', 'O3', 'O3_UNIT',
             'PM10', 'PM10_UNIT', 'PM25', 'PM25_UNIT', 'CO', 'CO_UNIT', 'TEMP',
             'TEMP_UNIT', 'HUM', 'HUM_UNIT', 'AIRPRES', 'AIRPRES_UNIT', 'WS',
             'WS_UNIT', 'WD', 'WD_UNIT', 'NO', 'NO_UNIT', 'BENZENE', 'BENZENE_UNIT']]
    return df
```

Then I'm planning to put all the df on a list and then use a for loop to run the function on each of the df.

[image: 'This is how my df looks']

Here you see the headers and the first three rows:

```
print(gharb.head(3).to_dict())
{'TIMESTAMP': {0: '26/01/2022 14:00', 1: '26/01/2022 13:00', 2: '26/01/2022 12:00'}, 
'NO2': {0: '1.3 µg/m3', 1: '1.41 µg/m3', 2: '2.11 µg/m3'}, 
'SO2': {0: '0.78 µg/m3', 1: '0.81 µg/m3', 2: '0.89 µg/m3'}, 
'O3': {0: '90.05 µg/m3', 1: '88.33 µg/m3', 2: '86.41 µg/m3'}, 
'PM10': {0: '1.9 µg/m3', 1: '2.18 µg/m3', 2: '3.28 µg/m3'}, 
'CO': {0: '0.19 mg/m3', 1: '0.19 mg/m3', 2: '0.19 mg/m3'}, 
'TEMP': {0: '10.1 °C', 1: '9.99 °C', 2: '9.79 °C'}, 
'HUM': {0: '64.98 %', 1: '63.59 %', 2: '64.63 %'}, 
'WS': {0: '4.92 m/s', 1: '5.24 m/s', 2: '5.37 m/s'}, 
'WD': {0: '249.15 Deg', 1: '232.48 Deg', 2: '238.07 Deg'}, 
'NO': {0: '0.12 µg/m3', 1: '0.14 µg/m3', 2: '0.31 µg/m3'}, 
'PM2.5': {0: 'None', 1: 'None', 2: 'None'}, 
'AIRPRES': {0: 'None', 1: 'None', 2: 'None'}, 
'BENZENE': {0: 'None', 1: 'None', 2: 'None'}}
```

Comment: Can you add a code to create your dataframe?

Comment: @Irfanuddin the dfs come from xlsx files.

Comment: IIUC your problem, you have some NaN in the columns. But your statements in the `if` are not checking that at all.  And actually they are all True because you check if the string NO2 is different to the the string NaN, which is always True. as @Irfanuddin said, share some data. to do so, load in a df, then edit the question here with the result of print(df.head(10).to_dict()). In case too many columns in the input, just select the sones you are performing your operations

Comment: @Ben.T done. I added the print(df.head(10).to_dict()).

Comment: in your last three columns, it seems that each cell is a string representation of a Series, is it expected?

Comment: @Ben.T  I was just checking this last three columns. Now I have them all with 'None'. I updated it so you can see it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way that should work with your input data:

```
def formatting(df):
    """ split text columns into two columns and changes data type"""

    # setting all floats to 2 digits in general
    pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2f}".format
    
    # define all the columns to perform the split
    # could also be an input of the function
    cols = [ 'NO2', 'SO2', 'O3', 'PM10', 'CO', 'TEMP', 'HUM', 'WS',
            'WD', 'NO', 'PM2.5', 'AIRPRES', 'BENZENE']
    
    # to get all result columns available
    res_cols = ['TIMESTAMP']
    # iterate over the columns to split
    for col in cols:
        #use try/except instead of if to be able to handle weird columns
        try: 
            # add the column to select in the result
            res_cols.append(col) 
            # now split the column and expand one time only, in case several space
            df[[col, col+'_UNIT']] = df[col].astype(str).str.split(' ', expand=True, n=1)
            # add the unit column only if the split works
            res_cols.append(col+'_UNIT') 
        # in case of the split does not work
        except ValueError:
            print(f'Error for column {col}')
        # from string to float, coerce (aka replace by NaN) if not possible
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast="float", errors='coerce')
     

    # order columns
    df = df[res_cols]
    return df
```

and now you get. You can remove the print in the except if you don't care.

```
df = formatting(df)
# Error for column PM2.5
# Error for column AIRPRES
# Error for column BENZENE
print(df)
#           TIMESTAMP  NO2 NO2_UNIT  SO2 SO2_UNIT    O3 O3_UNIT  PM10 PM10_UNIT  \
# 0  26/01/2022 14:00 1.30    µg/m3 0.78    µg/m3 90.05   µg/m3  1.90     µg/m3   
# 1  26/01/2022 13:00 1.41    µg/m3 0.81    µg/m3 88.33   µg/m3  2.18     µg/m3   
# 2  26/01/2022 12:00 2.11    µg/m3 0.89    µg/m3 86.41   µg/m3  3.28     µg/m3   

#     CO CO_UNIT  TEMP TEMP_UNIT   HUM HUM_UNIT   WS WS_UNIT     WD WD_UNIT  \
# 0 0.19   mg/m3 10.10        °C 64.98        % 4.92     m/s 249.15     Deg   
# 1 0.19   mg/m3  9.99        °C 63.59        % 5.24     m/s 232.48     Deg   
# 2 0.19   mg/m3  9.79        °C 64.63        % 5.37     m/s 238.07     Deg   

#     NO NO_UNIT  PM2.5  AIRPRES  BENZENE  
# 0 0.12   µg/m3    NaN      NaN      NaN  
# 1 0.14   µg/m3    NaN      NaN      NaN  
# 2 0.31   µg/m3    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Note that if you rerun the fonction of df, you get print a error print for all the columns, but the result is still good.

Comment: It works!!! thank you so much